# MATLAB - Issue with buffer() to split vector

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Consider the following MATLAB code:

```
x = zeros(1, 500);
overlap_percentage = 0.5;
total_frames = 10;
frame_length =  length(x)/total_frames;
overlapping_frames = overlap_percentage*total_frames;
y = buffer(x, frame_length, overlapping_frames);
```

I want to split my signal x into 10 seperate frames with a 50% overlap between adjacent frames (internal of course, don't want first elements of first frame to overlap with last elements of last frame). So I use the code above.

**Now surely, the resulting y array should have 10 frames of size 50? It doesn't. It has 12 frames of size 50. That means buffer() split it up into 12 different frames not 10. Why?**

Comment: EDIT: I think I just figured it out. Since I have overlapping sequences, there is no way for my frames to equal the length of x. It will always be bigger.

Comment: Since you have an answer, it would be helpful if you could either write it as an answer or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. Since I have overlapping sequences, there is no way for my frames to equal the length of x. It will always be bigger